# Latest version of ruamel.yaml fails to parse simple flow mapping

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

Posting this here instead of Bitbucket because I'm really unsure about whether or not this is user error. Something simple like this broke after upgrading to the latest version:

```
>>> from ruamel import yaml
>>> test_str = '{"in":{},"out":{}}'
>>> yaml.safe_load(test_str)

ruamel.yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a flow mapping
  in "<byte string>", line 1, column 1:
    {"in":{},"out":{}}
    ^ (line: 1)
expected ',' or '}', but got '<scalar>'
  in "<byte string>", line 1, column 6:
    {"in":{},"out":{}}
         ^ (line: 1)
```

Putting spaces after `"in"` and `"out"` resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, this was indeed a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in ruamel.yaml<0.15.30.

The token scanner had been changed a few micro versions earlier, in order to allow `::`  and `?`to occur in plain scalars (as required by the 1.2 specification, see example 7.10), and those changes affected this, "compact JSON", syntax.

One workaround, if you cannot upgrade `ruamel.yaml`, which may be easier than changing all your YAML input, is loading this explicitly as YAML 1.1:

```
from ruamel import yaml
test_str = '{"in":{},"out":{}}'
yaml.safe_load(test_str, version="1.1")
```